# Custom topmatter variable

Tags: environment-variables

In a simple documentclass for homework assignments, how should I go about specifying a few attributes in addition to `title` and `author` in the topmatter?

```
\begin{document}
\acadclass{Linear Algebra}
\psetnum{2}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Joe Shmoe}
```

I would like this to render stuff like "Linear Algebra - Pset 2" in the header by evaluating `\@acadclass - Pset \@psetnum`. How can I declare these variables in the documentclass such that I could access them from `\@acadclass`?

Comment: Thanks :) It's a work in progress based on some other hw class I found on the net. Here's a gist of the current draft. It's pretty messy though. https://gist.github.com/mlsteele/6487153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for inspiration in the definition of `\author` in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
```

An example with your commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\acadclass[1]{\def\@acadclass{#1}}
\newcommand\psetnum[1]{\def\@psetnum{#1}}
\fancyhead[C]{\@acadclass--Pset~\@psetnum}
\makeatother

\acadclass{Linear Algebra}
\psetnum{2}


\acadclass{Linear Algebra}
\psetnum{2}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Joe Shmoe}

\begin{document}

test
\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting page showing the header:

[image]

To have also the header if `\maketitle` is used, add

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
```

inside

`\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`.

If these definitions are going to be used in a `.cls` file, you can do

```
\@ifpackageloaded{fancyhdr}{}{}{\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\acadclass[1]{\def\@acadclass{#1}}
\newcommand\psetnum[1]{\def\@psetnum{#1}}
\fancyhead[C]{\@acadclass--Pset~\@psetnum}
```

(in particular, in a `.cls` file, you do *not* use `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`).

Comment: Thanks! I had some issues because my documentclass somehow relies on @ being a letter. So I just put \makeatother at the end of the documentclass.

Comment: @Miles if you are talking about a `.cls` file, that indicates that you are using `\makeatletter` somewhere; if that is so, delete that command from your `.cls` file (and any possible `\makeatother`). `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` inside a `.cls` file are dangerous.

Comment: Yep, I'm talking about a `.cls`. Is it true then that `.cls` files are already in a scope where `@` is a letter, and that in a `.tex` file the scope is automatically switched so that `@` is an other?

Comment: @Miles yes; with the deafult settings, in a `.cls` (or a `.sty`) file `@` is a letter (has catcode 11); in a `.tex` file `@` is an other (has catcode 12).